# Найти сумму значения в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Необходимо проверить массив и сделать так что бы при сложении с переменной $k функция вернула сумму значения 10

```
$newarrss = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9];
$k = 3;
function foo($newarrss, $k) {}
```

Comment: В чём проблема?

Comment: Да собственно в том что я не силен в php и пока что трудно понять логику. Нашел такую задачу пытаюсь решить возможными способами

Comment: Не совсем понятна задача. В чем назначение функции? Вам нужно чтобы функция проходила по массиву, и проверяла будет ли $k + $newarrss[$i] равно 10? И если да возвращала элемент массива? Или как?

Comment: Ну по сути наверное да. То есть функция должна вывести правильный результат он 10

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Можете как-то уточнить логику того, что делает ваша функция.

Comment: У нас есть массив со значениями и переменная которая равна 3. Функция которая принимает массив и значение и работает с ними. Ну и соответственно я хочу найти решение что бы функция прошла по массиву и выбрала нужное значение то есть 7 и если правильно то вернуло результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, получается, что ли? в теме одно, в комментариях другое...

```
$newarrss = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9];
$k = 3;
function showResult($array, $val) {
    foreach($array as $arr){
        if ($arr+$val==10) {
            return 10;
        }
    }
    return 'no matches found';
}
echo showResult($newarrss, $k);
```

Comment: Не совсем то.Нам функция вернула 7 элемент массива а надо что бы при сложении $k b нужного элемента массива получилось 10

Comment: @Freemanvavilon не знаю где вы это задание получили, но бегите оттуда и чем быстрей - тем лучше..

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то вот код который делает ровным счетом то, что вы описали. Но мне кажется я не до конца понимаю логику данной функции.

```
$newarrss = [1, 3, 4, 7, 9];
$k = 3;
function foo($newarrss, $k) {
    foreach($newarrss as $val){
        if ($k+$val==10) {
            return 10;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем то.Мы значение которое быдем складывать не знаем. По идее это как то надо пройти по массиву и проверить если элемен при сложении вернет 10 тогда ок иначе дальше проверять

Comment: Окей, теперь понятно, я исправил ответ.